# Serializing a Double for transmit over UDP (ARM to x86)

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I am trying to serialize a Double (on an ARM) in some C++ (QT) code and sending it to x86 via UDP. Both devices are Little Endian, both running Linux. My questions are, is it safe to assume that both are using IEEE-754?

My initial attempts did not seem to work. I did the following and sent it via datagram.

```
void QSendDouble::Send()
{
   // Start value is 19.231, value increments by 1 each second
   dblval = dblval + 1.0;

   QByteArray packet;
   packet.append('\xAA'); // Start Marker
   packet.append('\xAA'); // Start Marker

   QByteArray data(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&dblval), sizeof(dblval));
   packet.append(data);

   packet.append('\xFF'); // End Marker
   packet.append('\xFF'); // End Marker

   udpsocket->writeDatagram(packet.constData(), QHostAddress::LocalHost, 7711);
}
```

My belief is that I have made some wrong assumptions.

QT is used to send a Double encoded as a byte array, and Python is used to receive the bytes on the x86 end.

Comment: Do both sides use Qt? If so, what versions of Qt do you use?

Comment: Please show the Python code as well. Your QT code is fine, so you are likely not decoding the bytes properly on the Python side.

Comment: AFAIK all current C++ implementations do use IEEE standard for doubles.  Try getting a wireshark trace and seeing what you're sending, and also passing the message on the same system to check it is translating back and forth correctly.

Comment: Can you use PyQt5 or PySide2 on the python side? What version of Qt do you use?

Comment: Whether you make assumptions or not, you should still document the packet format at the byte level. That way, if you are wondering whether things are working correctly, you can dump the packet bytes and check the sender independently.

Comment: @david-schwartz - You are correct, I will update my answer. To Remy -  I ditched the Python tool I was using and just used netcat and good hexdump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the question and using xxd and netcat I observed the following data:

%> nc -l -u -p 2488 | xxd -u -cols 12

```
00000000: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3440 FFFF  ..B`..";4@..
0000000c: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3540 FFFF  ..B`..";5@..
00000018: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3640 FFFF  ..B`..";6@..
00000024: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3740 FFFF  ..B`..";7@..
00000030: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3840 FFFF  ..B`..";8@..
0000003c: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3940 FFFF  ..B`..";9@..
00000048: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3A40 FFFF  ..B`..";:@..
00000054: AAAA 4260 E5D0 223B 3B40 FFFF  ..B`..";;@..
```

I used Christopher Vickery's IEEE 754 Analyzer(https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) to look at the values. And looking at the first value it produced a result of:

```
Decimal value: 2.023100000000000164845914696343243122100830078125E1

Normalized binary value: 1.010000111011001000101101000011100101011000000100001b4
```

Which is what I would expect. Yes the values are little Endian as I expected, and they are being transmitted correctly.

So the culprit was the tool I was using to originally examine the data (*which I can trouble shoot*).